# How to expand lists nested in DataFrame columns to their own columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I've just started working with the Pandas library for Python, and I've hit upon a problem that I can't work out.

```
dictionary = {key:list}
series = pd.Series(dictionary)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(series)
print(dataframe)
```

So the output is:

```
    0
key list
key list
key list
key list
```

I want to get that list and have every value in the list have it's own column like this:

```
       0    1    2    3    4
key val0 val1 val2 val3 val4
key val0 val1 val2 val3 val4
key val0 val1 val2 val3 val4
key val0 val1 val2 val3 val4
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create the DataFrame from the dictionary, but when creating that, the `keys` would become the column and `0`/`1` , etc would become the indices, if you want it the other way round - `keys` as indices and `0`/`1` , etc as columns - you can then take its transpose.

Please note, all keys should have same amount of elements in the lists.

Code -

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dictionary).T
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: d = {'key1':[1,2,3,4],'key2':[2,3,4,5],'key3':[3,4,5,6]}

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(d).T

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
      0  1  2  3
key1  1  2  3  4
key2  2  3  4  5
key3  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can accomplish this is to skip creating a pandas series altogether and just go right to a DataFrame, then transpose the dataframe:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dict = {1: ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'],
   ...:         2: ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'],
   ...:         3: ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'],
   ...:         4: ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']}
```

Read the dictionary into the DataFrame, then transpose it with `.T`, or with `transpose()`:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict).T

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
      0     1     2     3     4
1  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
2  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
3  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
4  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
```